# Angular translate plugin not firing up

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular-i18n

I have installed [the Angular Translator plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RohanAgarwal-Vscode.angular-translator#overview) but it doesn't seems to work.

- I've tried using the default shortcut: "ctrl + alt + T";
- I've tried changing the shortcut to "alt + t";
- I've tried using it through the command prompt: [image]

But nothing is happening and I don't get any error messages.

I'm using VSCode 1.38.1 and Angular 8.

Any idea why I'm not able to use this plugin?
I will also accpet a reliant alternative as an answer to my question.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 7):

See the [documentation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RohanAgarwal-Vscode.angular-translator&ssr=false#overview) and make sure that your solution has both the folder created and the package installed.

> ## Requirements
>
> There should be an **i18n** folder inside the **src** folder with an **en.json** File.
>
> This extension assumes that Angular Project should has the npm package [@ngx-translate/core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/%40ngx-translate/core) installed.
>
> ## Known Issues
>
> The extension will not work if the requirement specified above is not met. **It will not create a file automatically in case it is not found.**

Answer (score 2):

Make Sure you have the @ngx-translate/core installed in the project. Go to project folder and install the package library with this command: npm i @ngx-translate/core

Answer (score 2):

After looking at the plugin, it doesn't seem like a good way to do your translations.  Piping everything could have a negative effect on performance and it is not the official Angular way of doing it.

I would follow the i18n guide that Angular provides and correctly tag your items with the i18n tag and then utilize the angular cli, (e.g. `ng xi18n --output-path src/i18n`) to generate your translation files.  Last I checked, you still had to do a separate build for each language, but pre-compiled performance is way superior to on-the-fly.  This is quite a rabbit hole and beyond the scope of this question, but I think you'll have better results in the long term if you step away from the plugin altogether.

Angular guide on i18n: https://angular.io/guide/i18n

Some additional info on i18n: https://medium.com/@feloy/deploying-an-i18n-angular-app-with-angular-cli-fc788f17e358

Answer (score 0):

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RohanAgarwal-Vscode.angular-translator#overview

> Makes the corresponding entry of the selected string in en.json file,
>   with a maximum key lenght of 5 words. Duplicate entries are not made.
>   adds translate pipe adds to en.json
>
> **Requirements** There should be an i18n folder inside the src folder with
>   an en.json File.
>
> This extension assumes that Angular Project should has the npm package
>   **@ngx-translate/core installed**.
>
> Known Issues The extension will not work if the requirement specified
>   above is not met. It will not create a file automatically in case it
>   is not found.

if it is **not resolve** uninstall extension and close VS code then re open VScode then install **again and reopen IDE**